# Can I get the result of local memory in OpenCL?

Tags: opencl

In the OpenCL, I have 2 work groups, and each 100 work items in it. So I will do some thing like this:

```
....
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&hDeviceMemInput);  
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&hDeviceMemOutput); 
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_float) * 100, NULL);
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 3, sizeof(cl_int) * 1, &mCount);

clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(CmdQueue, Kernel, 1, 0, 200, 100, 0, 0, 0); 
....
```

OpenCL code :

```
__kernel square(
__global float *input,
__global float *output,
__local float *temp,
const unsigned int count)
{
int gtid = get_global_id(0);
int ltid = get_local_id(0);
if (gtid < count)
{
    temp[ltid] = input[gtid];
    output[gtid] =  temp[ltid] * temp[ltid];
}
}
```

As I understand, each group has a float[100] local temp variable. In my case, there are two float[100] on device. If there are n work group, there are n float[100] on the device. Is that right? Is __local float *temp just used on device? Can I access it out of the kernel, by using something like:

```
clEnqueueReadBuffer(CmdQueue, ??, CL_TRUE, 0, 100* sizeof(cl_float),  
    host_temp, 0, 0, 0);
```

Is the local memory much faster than global memory? Do you have tip for using local memory?

Answer (score 2):

Local memory is a very fast temporal memory. So, no you can't access it or read it back. Because it is overwritten continuously. In fact the memory is not reserved in the device, so it can be the case (and it will be) that your 2 work groups use the same local memory but at different times. If you have 100 groups and 2 compute unit... imagine how many times the overwrite will ocur.

If you want to read the result of local memory you have to copy it first to global, then read from there.

Local memory intention is to share something between the work-items for a temporal intermediate result and fast access. After that it will be destroyed. This is usefull for many things, one simple example is filtering an image.

**EDIT:**

You can think about local memory as a register, a HW resource. You can't use a register as RAM. The same as you can't use local memory as global memory.

Comment: Sometimes if you fill the capacity, it spills to global memory, most probably the last written ones.